# How to consume Restful web services in spring rest

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I would like to know how to consume Restful web service in spring mvc. I saw an example they user @RestController  instead of using @Controller is the way to convert our mvc into restful service? and how data will be passed between service and client?.

Comment: I do no how Web service get data belongs to client.i think it will get by having same pojo class. Im not familiar with maven but in that they add our client program in dependencies.

Comment: If u do no please don't answer am new to this don't give negative mark to my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to know, is how a client can consume a webservice without knowing the APi contrat.
Well you have many choice, for example, you can create your models (Requests,Responses) manually, depending on the JSON contract, for that your must show on the browser on another tool like postman, the request/response in JSon, after that you can use some other toot, to transfrom thoses json data to class, i generally use maven for that, but you can do it [manually](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) .

On the other hand, use an OPEN API like swagger, to describe your API, after you build your webservice Rest, you can generate a client which contains all data(requests,responses, operations GET, POST,...)  [for more information](https://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/)

Good Luck !!